# Get AWS Auto Scaling Group metrics in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I have created auto scaling group via UI. I want to get all "General" metrics in cloudwatch.
I want to get following metrics:

```
General GroupMinSize Average                     
General GroupMaxSize Average                     
General GroupDesiredCapacity Average                     
General GroupInServiceInstances Average                  
General GroupPendingInstances Average                    
General GroupTerminatingInstances Average
```

How can I get these metrics in cloud watch?

Answer (score 2):

First InstanceMonitoring.Enabled property must be true for autoscale group. The value is default True so it doesn't matter a problem. Also you have to open metrics. You can easly open all with CLI :

```
aws autoscaling enable-metrics-collection --auto-scaling-group-name basic-auto-scaling-group --granularity "1Minute"
```

[reference page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/enable-metrics-collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

While creating ASG please select "detailed monitoring" option. I got these metrics only for widows ec2 instance in one ASG.